# Resharper CLI Instability and Machine Set-up

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, static-analysis, resharper-10.0

I'm trying to use the Resharper CLI tools within our CI set-up to perform static code analysis.

I've tried this on two different VMs and got very different results, on one machine everything seems to work fine on another it seems very unstable.

Sometimes I got errors like access violations, sometimes it seems to be realted to the logger crashing, but even if I get no errors it doesn't seem to find all the projects in the solution during the analysis.

Both machines set-up is:

```
JetBrains Inspect Code 10.0.2
Running in 64-bit mode, .NET runtime 4.0.30319.34209 under Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0
```

The main difference between the machines is one has Visual Studio installed and one doesn't.

On the machine that is unstable I do see errors related to imported projects not being found (such as Microsoft.Portable.CSharp.targets) which i think are related to Visual Studio not being installed?

I also see:

```
PlatformInfo must be found for platformId=.NetFramework,Version=v4.5
```

Could anyone tell me what the minimum requirements are on a machine for running the Resharper CLI and is Visual Studio part of the requirements? And in particular what would cause the tool to not be able to find all the projects in a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out the failure to find all the files was because certain projects in the solution were being ignored because of missing or invalid references.

The fix was to install the following to the build box.

- Xamarin for Visual Studio (we are building Xamarin applications)
- Portable class library support as detailed here: http://lastexitcode.com/blog/2014/11/16/InstallingPortableClassLibrariesForXamarinStudio/
- .NET 4.5.1 Developer Pack: https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=40772

With all this installed the analysis appears to be working fine.